# People "of different kinds" vs. "different kinds of" people: why is the latter grammatical?

Tags: noun-phrases

Original title: NP + "of different kinds" vs. "different kinds of" + NP

This question has haunted me for years. It pops up almost every time I want to write down *types*, *kinds*, or *sorts*.

Below is a sentence from *General Linguistics: An Introductory Survey* by Robert Henry Robins:

> [S]ome languages combine morphological complexity with a fairly rigid order of words in **sentences of different syntactic types**.

I couldn't tell if it makes a practical difference here to rewrite it as

> [S]ome languages combine morphological complexity with a fairly rigid order of words in **different syntactic types of sentences**.

At first sight that may be too silly of a question, but I myself used to go to "NP + of different kinds" in my writing because I thought placing the NP as such could assert its status as the head, beneficially preventing any confusion. However, more often than not do I encounter sentences like:

> It is well known that **certain types of people** buy certain types of products.

Of course people buy products; should I parse the above sentence as "types buy types" in accordance with the structure?

Comment: As far as I can see, it makes no difference in meaning and is just a matter of style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in recognizing that what you call the NP (and not "type", "kind", etc.) makes more sense as the head of the overall phrase. The reason is apparent in your last example:

> It is well known that certain types of people buy certain types of products.

This sentence literally says that "certain types" buy "certain types" (as you've noted). Of course, a "type" can't buy anything. Therefore, the structure that you've been using would seem to be more logical:

> It is well known that people of certain types buy products of certain types.

However, the former construction is commonly understood to have the same meaning as the latter; that is one of the vagaries of English. By the way, the same is true even with singular number:

> It is well known that a certain type of person buys a certain type of product.
> It is well known that a person of a certain type buys a product of a certain type.

The first version is more common; here is [an ngram from Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=certain%20type%20of%20person%2Cperson%20of%20a%20certain%20type&year_start=1900&corpus=26&smoothing=3)<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

Nevertheless, both versions are correct, and their meanings are identical.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that using different words (instead of "person" and "type") can yield quite different results. I'm not including additional graphs for the sake of brevity, but feel free to use Ngrams to see which combinations are more or less common (but keep in mind that it only searches the Google Books corpus).

Comment: When we use ["people" instead of "person",](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=certain+type+of+people%2Cpeople+of+a+certain+type&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) the frequency comes closer to normal usage levels.

Comment: @gotube Yeah, the difference in the example I picked seems a bit extreme. Let me know if you think I should add some more examples so it doesn't seem as if one structure is so much more common than the other. (I'm a bit hesitant to make the answer longer unless it's really useful.)

Comment: I think just replacing the "person" graph with the "people" graph would solve the issue without making your answer longer.

Comment: @gotube I threw the most common variations into a single graph and added a footnote. Hopefully that works.